# Turn Off YouTube Related Videos using the jqvideobox plugin

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, jquery-plugins

I am using jqvideobox plugin for displaying some YouTube videos in my site. My code:

```
$(".vidbox").jqvideobox({
    width: 625,     
    height: 400
});

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGg9cKDljnk" target="_blank" class="vidbox">
```

I want to disable the related YouTube videos at the end of my video. I tried add rel=0 at the end of the URL, so make it like

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGg9cKDljnk&rel=0" target="_blank" class="vidbox">
```

But then the video is not working at all.
Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you used `&rel=0` instead of `?rel=0` in your link `href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGg9cKDljnk&rel=0"`. That should solve it.